# Listar Archivos de Servidor FTP

Tags: c#, uwp, ftp

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación simple que me permita listar los archivos de un servidor FTP pero no he conseguido hacerlo.
Si alguien tiene una forma simple de hacerlo quedaría muy agradecido.

Comment: de que forma lo has tratado agrega tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación oficial puedes encontrar un ejemplo para realizar un listado de archivos dentro de un folder ftp, modifique un poco el código ya que originalmente usa ListDirectoryDetails y ahora con [ListDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) obtiene una lista "corta" de los archivos:

```
   using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Examples.System.Net
    {
        public class WebRequestGetExample
        {
            public static void Main ()
            {
                // Obtiene el objeto que se utiliza para comunicarse con el servidor.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

                // Este ejemplo asume que el sitio FTP utiliza autenticación anónima.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                List<string> directories = new List<string>();

                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                //Obtiene el contenido y lo agrega al List<string>.
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                   directories.Add(line);
                   line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }

                 streamReader.Close();

                //Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

                Console.WriteLine("Estatus al listar el contenido del folter {0}", response.StatusDescription);

               // reader.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

[**Cómo: Mostrar el contenido de directorio con FTP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx) (inglés)

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero al parecer FTPWebRequest no esta disponible para aplicaciones UWP. Hay que utilizar sockets pero aun no encuentro un tutorial sencillo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar este código en una libreria de clases, compilarala y simplemente en tu aplicación utilizarla como una referencia.